# react native unexpected content found on stack

Tags: android, react-native

I saw this error when I ran the app:

[image]

react-native: 0.56.0
Below are the main APP.JS codes. It imports a simple module src/InstClone.js.

APP.JS codes:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import InstClone from './src/InstClone.js';


export default class App extends Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <InstClone />

                {/* <Text> Hello World!</Text> */}

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  }, 
});
```

Codes in src/InstClone.js. It simply renders a view with text there.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, Image, StyleSheet} from "react-native";

class InstClone extends Component {

    render(){
        return (
            <view>
                <Text> Hello World!</Text>
            </view>

        );
    }
}


export default InstClone;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats may be because you are using `view` instead of `View` in your `InstClone`

Comment: That is right. I changed to View and it is working now. Thanks!